# Spell checker in the WebBrowser Control for IE10

Tags: .net, webbrowser-control

Has anyone got the spell checker feature of IE10 to work in the .NET WebBrowser control?

I've done all the obvious things - set up HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\MAIN\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION to use IE10 mode, tried adding meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=10" to the header etc.

"$.browser.version" shows as "10.0" for both standalone and .NET embedded.

When I was using IE9, I was using the IE9 features in my WebBrowser control just fine (set via the registry entries), but I'm having issues with IE10.

My buttons also appear to be different standalone vs .NET embedded as well.

Answer (score 1):

It depends what version of the Windows you are using, but if you are using Internet Explorer 10 on Windows 7 then spell checking is not supported. It is supported only on Windows 8 with Internet Explorer 10 (or newer) as it seems.

See the following question as a reference to this - it also includes some additional registry keys required to get spell checker working (at least under Windows 8):

[Spell checker in TWebBrowser (TEmbeddedWB) control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19299326/spell-checker-in-twebbrowser-tembeddedwb-control)